# cygwin installation Windows 8.1

Tags: c, eclipse, cygwin, eclipse-neon

I downloaded Eclipse Neon and tried to work sample program but it's giving issue at

```
#include<stdio.h>
```

Warning is:Unresolved inclusion:
I went through some posts and found out we should install Cygwin to proceed working. While Installing Cygwin,there is an option Choose a download site and there are many links .I can't move to next step until I choose one of the links. What link should be chosen here?
I have attached the screenshot of installation too. 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W0aOU.png)

Comment: It doesn't matter what link you choose, at the end you want Cygwin installed.They are suggested because you can download from any of the site, if not try another.

Comment: You **probably** want MinGW instead of Cygwin if your goal is to compile C programs for Windows. Cygwin is a complete POSIX environment and allows POSIX programs to be compiled and run on Windows, but for running such a program, you will need the Cygwin libs.

Comment: Hello Thank you. I installed and connected to eclipse but after writing program I still get this warning question mark 
#include<stdio.h>
Unresolved Inclusion:<stdio.h>

Answer (score 1):

You can choose one of these links. It's exactly the same. After the installation, you have to change the `PATH` into your environment variables and add the path of the `bin` folder of Cygwin. 
You can test your installation with typing `sys` into the shell.

Comment: Hello Thanks I did installation part but I still get this warning question mark 
#include<stdio.h>
Unresolved Inclusion:<stdio.h>

Comment: Try to install the libraries for C/C++ in your environment.